# Android force Fragment redraw when screen change orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, screen-orientation

My app is structured with Navigation Drawer and 4 Fragments.
The old version of this app uses Activities so I need to transform that Activities in Fragments.

For now all works well but in one `Fragment` i have 80 `Buttons` that user can set text and background color and the method that call `DialogActivity` is in the only one `MainActivity` that manage all `Fragments` and `onActivityResults` called by Dialogs inside `Fragments` for manage user change.

**The problem occurs when the screen orientation change to landscape.**
If i press `Buttons` and set text and color all works **with portrait** but if a change orientation of screen with landscape i get something like "shadow" like background and the Buttons that i have doesn't change their properties when i click them, but if i rotate again the screen the changed buttons became visible.
The strange things is that in the Fragment background i see the buttons with the right updates but not in the top... (i post a photo, it's hard to explain)

The old buttons that i change remain changed because i save it to DB, but with landscape i can't update che other buttons...

[image]

CODE:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    static String clickedButtonViewId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (findViewById(R.id.content_frame) != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, new OrarioFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_orario) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new OrarioFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_calendario) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new CalendarioFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_voti) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new VotiFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_registrazioni) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new RegistrazioniFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    public void addMateria(View v){

        /* Prendo il nome della risorsa cosi nel ricompilare il progetto non perdo *
         * tutti i riferimenti ai bottoni salvati nel database                     */

        clickedButtonViewId = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());

        //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityAddMateria.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
        //onStop();
    }

    //Take back data from ActivityAddMateria
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

                //Cambio subito il Button
                int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(clickedButtonViewId, "id", getPackageName());
                final Button clickedtextView = (Button) findViewById(resId);

                String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
                int color = data.getIntExtra("color", 1); //Take the color from Dialog

                //Controllo se il Button è già presente nel db se presente aggiorno se non presente inserisco
                boolean modifica = db.Exists(clickedButtonViewId);

                //Se voglio ripristinare il bottone di default
                if (color == getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_orario)) {

                    //Ripristino la grafica di Default
                    Drawable style = setButtonColor(color);
                    clickedtextView.setBackground(style);
                    clickedtextView.setText("New");

                    //Se la materia è nel database la cancello
                    if (modifica) {

                        db.deleteSingleMateria(clickedButtonViewId);

                    }

                } else {
                    //Quando inserisco un normale bottone colorato
                    if (!modifica) {

                        //Materia da inserire in un nuovo spazio
                        db.addMateriaToDb(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));

                    } else {

                        //Materia già presente nel Button quindi aggiorno la materia
                        db.updateMateria(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Materia modificata!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    //Inserisco la materia nel DB dei voti_media
                    db.addMateriaVotiFromOrario(new MaterieVoti(result, 0.0));

                    clickedtextView.setText(result);
                    //clickedtextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    //clickedtextView.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    Drawable style = setButtonColor(color);
                    clickedtextView.setBackground(style);
                }
            }

            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Nessuna materia inserita
            }

        }
    }//onActivityResult
```

**EDIT**

Ok i found the problem.

In the MainActivity i have this line of code for force the first fragment to be shown

```
 if (findViewById(R.id.content_frame) != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, new OrarioFragment()).commit();
        }
```

And when the screen orientation change the MainActivity is recreated and the if load the same fragment over the old fragment because i use .add()

So how can i set the fragment to shown when the app start avoiding this problem?

I'm wrong with managing the drawer?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Bryan added the code, if need more just tell :)

Comment: Can you share your layout also?

Comment: @JRG all two or only main_activity or fragmet?

Comment: Both will make things clear

Comment: Added all two the layouts, the second is cutted because too long

Comment: Don't know why i get downvote....when downvote a questions just post a comment about why or it's useless.
Thanks.

Comment: No one have idea to what happen?
And how i can solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Android Documentation that explains about saving states and a very good article on saving states in activity and fragment.

- `Android Documentation:` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html
- `Additional Article:` https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

> **Saving and restoring activity state** There are a few scenarios in which your activity is destroyed due to normal app behavior, such as when the user presses the Back button or your activity signals its own destruction by calling the finish() method. The system may also destroy the process containing your activity to recover memory if the activity is in the Stopped state and hasn't been used in a long time, or if the foreground activity requires more resources.
>
> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed. However, if the system destroys the activity due to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed. The saved data that the system uses to restore the previous state is called the instance state and is a collection of key-value pairs stored in a Bundle object.
>
> By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save information about each View object in your activity layout (such as the text value entered into an EditText widget). **So, if your activity instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is restored to its previous state with no code required by you. However, your activity might have more state information that you'd like to restore, such as member variables that track the user's progress in the activity.**
>
> **Save your activity state**
>   As your activity begins to stop, the system calls the onSaveInstanceState() method so your activity can save state information with a collection of key-value pairs. The default implementation of this method saves transient information about the state of the activity's view hierarchy, such as the text in an EditText widget or the scroll position of a ListView widget. Your app should implement the onSaveInstanceState() callback after the onPause() method, and before onStop(). Do not implement this callback in onPause().
>
> Caution: You must always call the superclass implementation of onSaveInstanceState() so the default implementation can save the state of the view hierarchy.
>
> To save additional state information for your activity, you must override onSaveInstanceState() and add key-value pairs to the Bundle object that is saved in the event that your activity is destroyed unexpectedly. For example:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);


    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

> Note: In order for the Android system to restore the state of the views in your activity, each view must have a unique ID, supplied by the android:id attribute.
>
> To save persistent data, such as user preferences or data for a database, you should take appropriate opportunities when your activity is in the foreground. If no such opportunity arises, you should save such data during the onStop() method.
>
> **Restore your activity state**
>   When your activity is recreated after it was previously destroyed, you can recover your saved state from the Bundle that the system passes to your activity. Both the onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState() callback methods receive the same Bundle that contains the instance state information.
>
> Because the onCreate() method is called whether the system is creating a new instance of your activity or recreating a previous one, you must check whether the state Bundle is null before you attempt to read it. If it is null, then the system is creating a new instance of the activity, instead of restoring a previous one that was destroyed.
>
> For example, the following code snippet shows how you can restore some state data in onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first


    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }
    ...
}
```

> Instead of restoring the state during onCreate() you may choose to implement onRestoreInstanceState(), which the system calls after the onStart() method. The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
}
```

> Caution: Always call the superclass implementation of onRestoreInstanceState() so the default implementation can restore the state of the view hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, but why i have a "shadow" like the photo when screen orientation change and why i can't see button change with screen landscape.

If i come back to portrait all work perfectly, it's the landscape the problem and don't think that the problem is the InstanceState.... no?

With the instanceState i can't avoid the "shadow" effect with landscape

Comment: Do you have same layout for both orientation or you have layout and layout-land folder for orientations?

Comment: same layout, i haven't two layout for the different screen orientation.
It's possible that i need to destroy fragment when screen orientation change?

Maybe the "shadowing" effects it's a overlap of two fragment UI?
Because the shadow in the background if i change a button with landscape i see the update in the shadow background, but not in the top (it's hard to explain :D )

Comment: In portrait mode i see the change in real time

Comment: This looks weird, why are you setting button_style as getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttons) when color is orario but for all other colors you have a colored button?

Comment: It's for set a school hour... the students can press buttons and set color for different school subjects...like english (blue), math (green) and the button take the color choose...i have a xml style for each color :D

For be sure i add more columns and with portrait the screen don't have problems, only with landscape i get UI problem with shadowind and no buttons update

Comment: added the content_frame.xml that show every fragments...but i don't understand why i get this problem only with landscape screen...
Same app with Activity instead of fragments all work well.

Comment: Maybe if i try to invalidate the Fragment when the orientation change?
Like a force redraw...